# robot-model-visualization in ros hydro

Tags: ros, ros-hydro, robot, model

[image: Rosanswers logo]

terminal output:
sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-robot-model-visualization
[sudo] password for jaysin:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ros-hydro-robot-model-visualization

it locates for ros-groovy but i need it for hydro.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/111096/robot-model-visualization-in-ros-hydro/) by [jay75](https://answers.ros.org/users/5740/jay75/) on ROS Answers with karma: 259 on 2013-12-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That package is not released in hydro, it's contents have been merged into robot_model.

http://wiki.ros.org/robot_model
http://wiki.ros.org/robot_model_visualization

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-12-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0